# OCAML how to find the next element of the variant

Tags: types, ocaml, variant

I have  -> type week = MON | TUE | WED......        I want to create the function tomorrow which return the next day! For example , if I call "tomorrow MON", the function will return TUE.

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in language construction which allows you to do this. So you should write the function yourself:

```
let tomorrow = function
  | MON -> TUE
  | TUE -> WED
  ...
```

Another possibility is to implement these functions:

```
val int_of_week: week -> int
val week_of_int: int -> week
```

It happens that those functions are trivial to write with Obj.magic. They would allow you to implement tomorrow as:

```
let tomorrow w =
  week_of_int ((int_of_week w + 1) mod 7)
```

which is probably closer to what you had in mind.

But this solution is less safe:

- function tomorrow assumes that int_of_week MON = 0, int_of_week TUE = 1 and so on;
- you need to document the behavior of week_of_int for integers which are not between 0 and 6;
- and, last but not least, Obj.magic is not actually part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Haskell, you cannot just do `deriving(Ord)` and call `succ`/`pred`
You will haveto code these functions by hand. For example

```
let tomorrow = function
  | MON -> TUE
  | TUE -> WED
  | (* etc.. *)
```